# How to completely replace redux with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I am thinking of using react hooks [useReducer, useContext] and context api in place of redux. Having said I want my state to be bit complex in structure. Lets see the structure be as

```
state = {
    key1: true,
    key2: {
        key3: [],
        key4: ''
    }
}
```

The thing that I am clear with is both redux and context api allows me to create complex structure. And in case of react hooks usage I can very well use Provider, Consumer/useContext to  let pass my store state value to all my components.

The thing that Redux gives me more is that if any specific key say, `key4`, is updated then helps me not to re-render entire app tree using connect function from `react-redux`. And this is my query.

> How can we make react hooks and context api to not to re-render my entire app which is a major performance bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something you just cannot achieve with only react context. Of course, you can trick around with useMemo so that the direct children of your Provider do not rerender, but apart from that: everytime any property of your context value changes, all consumers of said context will rerender, no matter if they used that specific property or not. You cannot bail out of a context rerender for some children only.

This might change in the future once `useContextSelector` is integrated in react, but for now, this is just standard React behaviour and there is no way around that.

You can find more on "context vs a real state management solution" [in this article](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2021/01/context-redux-differences/).

For now, if you just want to reduce boilerplate it is probably just better to read up on [modern redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) or to look into other full-fledged state management libraries like mobx or recoil. But you won't get there with context alone without fully reimplementing one of those - and where's the point in that?

Comment: As someone who is just starting to learn React, the article you linked was very useful. I am currently using Context + `useReducer` to manage state, but as the app I am developing adds more and more complexity (I have 5 state-related contexts), it's probably a good idea to start looking at Redux.

Comment: @Mike if you get started with redux, please follow the official tutorials at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index for this - those are up to date while a lot of other resources (even recently released ones) are fairly out of date and get several best practices wrong.

Comment: That's good to keep in mind. I'm currently going through https://www.udemy.com/course/react-redux, but I'm not at the Redux portions yet. I guess I should probably go through the official tutorials before I watch the videos.

Comment: I am quite aligned with the usage of redux for state management. But in the app people suggested to use apollo gql for state management which works on the concept of react hooks thats why I started looking to find ways to make all state a composite state just like we do in redux because of re-rendering trigger but figured out this issue when I thought about design. It could be annoying but do we have any third party libraries for doing the same as I asked?

Comment: That course is terribly outdated, both for React and for Redux knowledge. Unless you are going to work on a legacy project, you will not need knowledge of class components and you should definitely learn functional components and hooks *before* class components, as the mindset from class components will actually make it harder for you to understand hooks like `useEffect` correctly (as you will try to map that 1:1 on lifecycle actions, which does not really work 100%).

Comment: @ShubhamBhewanewala you should definitely be using hooks with redux - we only recommend to use `connect` with class components, otherwise you can work a lot better with `useSelector` and `useDispatch` - see the "modern redux" link up there.
Also, having Apollo is great, because from that point on you really only have to worry about real business logic and appliaction state and not about data caching any more - so redux + apollo make a great combination.

Comment: Yes.. but redux is not there to maintain global state.

Comment: Anyways thanks for tip. This sounds quite convincing to me to put towards other for involving usage of redux

Comment: The point of redux is to maintain global state. I'm on the redux team, I should know at least that much ;)

Comment: I mean in my app we are not using redux to maintain state. My bad with my words.

Comment: @phry Actually that course only briefly uses class components in the beginning, and the instructor even says that they're not used as much as functional components. The bulk of it uses functional components. That's one reason I chose that course over others because I knew that class components are not recommended for new projects anymore.

Comment: @Mike that does not change the fact that the course is heavily outdated. Redux Form is deprecated by the author for years and the Redux itself shown in that course is something we do not recommend any more for over two years now.

Comment: @phry, Yeah, you're right. The course was really outdated for a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Re-rendering component tree is something react manages well. Both redux and context api update component state which leads to a re-render. In terms of performance, if you are looking for a way to manage not necessary re-renders I suggest you have a look at a few useful hooks, `useMemo`, `useCallback`, and `React.memo`.

With these three hooks, you are able to prevent child components from re-rendering, if parent is updated.

```
const Parent = () => {

  const [childAState, setChildAState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setChildAState('Child A Updated');
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <ChildA childAState={childAState}/>
    <ChildB />
  );

};

const ChildA = () => React.memo((props) => {

  return <h1>Child A</h1>  

});

const ChildB = () => React.memo((props) => {

  return <h1>Child B</h1>  

});
```

In the above example, `ChildB` wont re-render if a state in `Parent` does change and leads to an update in `ChildA`.

For further reading: [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Comment: but still triggering re-render from top to bottom is not something we should do and this is what I am looking to avoid.

Comment: You can't avoid re-rendering. In fact on every state changes react would re-render all component tree depend on the component which is updated. You can just optimize it by controlling what to re-render and what not to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

I've alternative thoughts about this.

Instead of thinking that hook should or shouldn't completely replace Redux, And instead of using a context state with a giant complex data structure.

You might want to break it down into many little custom hooks.
For example,

```
const { name, pageCount } = useBook();
const { content, setContent } = useBookPage(i);
```

This gives me some important benefits

1. It's simpler to connect a simple data structure to smaller components.
2. Only small components under the little hook have to be re-render.
3. These hooks are individually managed it-self per list's item.

Now because there are many hooks spread around components, There must be a single source of truth to share across these hooks somewhere.
The question is how we could manage or inject the source of truth...

This is another issue and it depends.
You could use `useRef` to provide the plain object as a datastore.
You could use indexedDB, Redux, etc.

In the project I'm working on, All the data are stored within the external module library, So instead of using Redux, useRef, I fetch everything from that library.

I do still use the `Context.Provider` and `useContext` to inject those data stores and dependencies into my little hooks.

---

IMO, `useMemo` is hacky to solve this because the problem is you have a coupling of massive state managements in the first place.

Comment: Yes bro, we have the same idea. Can you share a github repo which implemented this concept?

Comment: It's still a private project. I'm sorry for that. But I can tell that it works pretty well man.

Answer (score -1):

if you really want to replace Redux using hooks I suggest using the useReducer and useContext hooks, they are easy to understand and quite flexible, here is an article that compares Redux and React hooks and detail:
https://www.framelessgrid.com/react-hooks-vs-redux-for-state-management-in-2021/